# Why does SpringJUnit4ClassRunner not work with surefire parallel=methods?

Tags: java, spring, junit, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

Why do my tests throw random exceptions when I use the surefire setting `parallel=methods` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because JUnit creates just one Runner instance per test class, which is used by multiple threads when using `parallel=methods`. `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` creates just one `TestContextManager`, which stores the test instance in an instance field, so it isn't thread safe.

When you use `parallel=classes` everything should be fine, because then JUnit creates one runner with a dedicated `TestContextManager` per thread.

I have filed a bug about that: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12421