# Spring @Autowired returning null when spawning threads in maven surefire plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, autowired

I am writing Junit test case using Spring and maven. I would like to run Junit test cases in parallel, for this I have used maven surefire plugin parallel property. This property is working as needed. But in my test case, `@Autowired` is returning null for 2nd thread.

pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.18.1</version>
<configuration>
    <parallel>methods</parallel>
    <threadCount>5</threadCount>                            
</configuration>
```

Class1.java

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Class1 {
    public void setParam(String s) {}
}
```

Class2.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class Class2 {
    @Autowired
    Class1 class1;

    @Before
    public void setInitialValue(){
        class1.setParam("test");
    }

    @Test
    public void run1() {
    }

    @Test
    public void run2() {}
}
```

In this code, `run1` and `run2` methods are called parallel but when thread 2 runs, `class1` object in `Class2`, `setInitialValue()` method is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed to put ", it will be class1.setParam("test")

Comment: in this question only. My problem is I am getting null for class1 object in this line class1.setParam("test");

Comment: setter for which variable/class and in which class?

Comment: public Class1 getClass1() {
  return class1;
 }

 public void setClass1(Class1 class1) {
  this.class1= class1;
 }
Created this in Class2, but still not working :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882936/why-does-springjunit4classrunner-not-work-with-surefire-parallel-methods

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but still.
When using `parallel=methods` JUnit creates only one Runner instance per test class, which is used by multiple threads.

When using `parallel=classes` JUnit creates one runner with a dedicated TestContextManager per thread, wich should fix the problem.

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882936/why-does-springjunit4classrunner-not-work-with-surefire-parallel-methods